# What differences (if any) are there between JFactory::getSession() and $mainframe->getSession()?

Tags: cms, session, jfactory

As the title states, I'm interested in knowing what differences there are (if any) between `JFactory::getSession() and $mainframe->getSession()`

This question was inspired by [Retrieve joomla session from within a module](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/998/retrieve-joomla-session-from-within-a-module)

If possible, I'd also like suggestions on how I could find out this information for myself in the future (please don't say google!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The global variable `$mainframe` was remove in Joomla 1.6 and therefore will not work from that version onwards.

`global $mainframe` should be replaced with `$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();` but most people tend to use `$app` instead.

So you code should be like this:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->getSession();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

As for ressources about `$mainframe`:

- [http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:What's_new_in_Joomla_2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aWhat%27s_new_in_Joomla_2.5)
- http://docs.joomla.org/Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6#Global_Variables_.28.24option_and_.24mainframe.29_are_Gone

(Found using Google)